# Collecting Metrics with Graphite Plugin leads to "A metric named [..] already exists" error

Tags: apache-flink

when i configure the *flink-conf.yaml* to collect metrics with the graphite plugin, 
the most time only incomplete metrics are being sent. On the Taskmanager output multiple errors occur like:

```
    2018-08-15 00:58:59,016 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - Error while registering metric.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named mycomputer.taskmanager.8ceab4c3dfbf9fc5fa2af0447f1373a1.State machine job.Source: Custom Source.0.numRecordsOut already exists
        at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.register(MetricRegistry.java:91)
        at org.apache.flink.dropwizard.ScheduledDropwizardReporter.notifyOfAddedMetric(ScheduledDropwizardReporter.java:131)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl.register(MetricRegistryImpl.java:329)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.AbstractMetricGroup.addMetric(AbstractMetricGroup.java:379)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.AbstractMetricGroup.counter(AbstractMetricGroup.java:312)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.AbstractMetricGroup.counter(AbstractMetricGroup.java:302)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.OperatorIOMetricGroup.<init>(OperatorIOMetricGroup.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.OperatorMetricGroup.<init>(OperatorMetricGroup.java:48)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.groups.TaskMetricGroup.addOperator(TaskMetricGroup.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.setup(AbstractStreamOperator.java:174)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.setup(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:82)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:143)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:267)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried this on a completely freshly prepared flink-1.6.0 release with following config and the precompiled "State machine job" in the examples folder:

```
    metrics.reporters: grph
    metrics.reporter.grph.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter
    metrics.reporter.grph.host: localhost
    metrics.reporter.grph.port: 2003
    metrics.reporter.grph.interval: 1 SECONDS
    metrics.reporter.grph.protocol: TCP
```

I use the official graphite docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/graphiteapp/docker-graphite-statsd/) that is running on the default configuration.

Has anybody an idea, how i can fix this issue?

Thank's and best regards

**update**

to exclude that a specific local setting is responsible for this behaviour, I repeated the process on a clean EC2 instance. There's exactly the same error here.

How to reproduce:

1. start EC2 t2.xlarge
2. installed java
3. download flink at https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/flink/flink-1.6.0/flink-1.6.0-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
4. added the flink-metrics-graphite-1.6.0.jar to lib
5. configured the flink-yaml.conf as mentioned in my previous post
6. ./bin/start-cluster.sh
7. ./bin/flink run examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar

I have not set up graphite in this case, because the error obviously already 
occurs before.
After the job has been started you can view the error in the flink dashboard under Task Manager -> Logs

Comment: Only having a very quick look at your question: Are the spaces in your metric name ("State Machine Job")  a problem?

Comment: Hi,

no, the names shouldn't be the problem.  I only chose this job because it is an example job in Flink and I can rule out that my implementation is wrong.  I have the same problem with my other jobs.

It is also remarkable that the error does not only occur with custom metrics, but with all of them.